# importing data into R from a text file

Tags: r, text, import, read.table, read.csv

[image]

I have hidden my student ID number which is also the text file name. I just want to know what I am doing wrong here. I am supposed to calculate the sample mean and sample standard deviation of the DBH (Tree.Diameter) of the trees in my text file. However I can not seem to import my text file into R with the code shown in the picture. it says there is no file in the directory. Also the text file contains data which should be read like a table because Tree.Diameter is a column and I need to find the mean for it.
The code I used is

```r
z******.txt <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
trees <- read.table("z******.txt", header=T, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. There's no picture here that you're referencing, but code should be in the post as text anyway, not an image

Comment: Just to let you know: Combining all places where you hid your students ID makes it possible to get your ID...

Comment: Why are you using `read.csv` _and_ `read.table`? Your `read.table`-function doesn't read `z****.txt` which you defined earlier. It looks for a file named `z****.txt` in your current working directory.